# Java - Get reference to a static class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, class, static

In Java, is it possible to access an instance of a static class (nested) using reflection?

Supposing I have the following 2 classes defined in the package **Package1.SubPackage.SubSubPackage:**

```
public class MyMainClass {  
   public static class SalesObjectGrouper1 {  
      public static final GrouperContext CONTEXT = new GrouperContext("MyDate");  
   }  

   private static class SalesObjectGrouper2 {  
      public static final GrouperContext CONTEXT = new GrouperContext("MyDate");  
   }  
}
```

If I run the following code:

```
try {
     xyz = Class.forName( "Package1.SubPackage.SubSubPackage.MyMainClass.SalesObjectGrouper1" );
} catch( ClassNotFoundException ex ) {
     // always hit the error
}
```

it will error indicating class cannot be found.  Can this be done?

Comment: btw using Class.forName() does not use reflection.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have you tried referring to the nested class as

```
MyMainClass$SalesObjectGrouper1
```

Nested classes are internally named ContainingClassName$NestedClassName

Answer (score 3):

To avoid hacks in the mapping of Java language classes on to the Java runtime classes, you could use `Class.getDeclaredClasses`. Using reflection is often a mistake. Dealing with nested classes does not seem to be a good sign.