# How to access Java Enum in ColdFusion?

Tags: java, coldfusion, enums, paypal

How to pass an Enum like [OAuthSignature.HTTPMethod](http://sandbox.boykin-interactive.com/PayPal/PP_Java_Windows__SOAP_SDK/paypal_java_sdk/docs/com/paypal/sdk/util/OAuthSignature.HTTPMethod.html#POST) as an argument to a Java method in ColdFusion?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found it:

```
createObject("java","com.paypal.sdk.util.OAuthSignature$HTTPMethod")
```

Thanks to : http://www.aguyinagarage.com/2011/02/using-java-enums-from-coldfusion/

Reference: [Java - Get reference to a static class using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357478/java-get-reference-to-a-static-class-using-reflection)